# Cómo puedo buscar automaticamente al seleccionar un dato del combo select en una tabla

Tags: html, jquery

Aquí tengo mi **Script y html**

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-block " id="btnBuscar" type="button" 
  value="Buscar">Buscar</button>
                <select id="cboCiudadDes">
                    <option>seleccionar</option>
                    <option>Cadiz</option>
                    <option>Westin</option>
                    <option>Sheraton</option>
                    <option>Barza</option>
                </select>


   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#btnBuscar").click(function () {
           // Buscar por Fecha            
           var table = document.getElementById("tabla").tBodies[0];
           var busquedaCiu = document.getElementById('cboCiudadDes');

           var textociudad = busquedaCiu.value.toLowerCase();
           var r = 0;
           while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
               if (row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(textociudad) !== -1 )
                   row.style.display = null;
               else
                   row.style.display = 'none';
           }
       });
   });
```

Comment: a que te refieres con buscar automáticamente?

Comment: al escribir en el combo el nombre al mismo tiempo que me busque en el tabla ese dato que estoy escribiendo, no se si me explico

Comment: Y como quieres escribir si tienes un select y no un input ?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es que se realice la búsqueda al seleccionar un valor del `select`, entonces podrías hacerlo así:

- Cada vez que se el valor del `select` cambia se dispar el evento `onchange`
- Si también necesitas que al seleccionar el `option` `seleccionar` se vean todas las filas, entonces deberías validar que el `textociudad` sea distinto de vacío.

### Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cboCiudadDes").on('change', function() {
    // Buscar por Fecha            
    var table = document.getElementById("tabla").tBodies[0];
    var textociudad = this.value.toLowerCase();
    var r = 0;
    while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
      if (!textociudad || row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(textociudad) !== -1)
        row.style.display = null;
      else
        row.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla" border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cadiz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Westin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sheraton</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<select id="cboCiudadDes">
    <option value="">seleccionar</option>
    <option>Cadiz</option>
    <option>Westin</option>
    <option>Sheraton</option>
    <option>Barza</option>
</select>
```